# debug array values at runtime C#

Tags: c#, debugging

Hi I am looking to check the values of a particular field in a stucture array. Is there a plugin or technique to achive this like immediate window.

```
struct products
{
    string product;
    int price;
}
```

`structure[i].Price` // there are 50 elements as the structure in the array 
want to fill int price field in all the array in a new array and sort it in ascending order.

Comment: Can you change the code? Simply create a method that does what you want and call it from the immediate window.

Comment: I am trying to figure out why you are creating a struct in c# I would assume just use a class with a constructor to initialize your variables.

Answer (score 1):

What version of visual studio are you using? In VS2015 the immediate and watch window got really powerful with roslyn. They now support lambdas, which enables you to use linq. You should be able to write something like the following in the immediate window for example:

```
int[] pricesArray = productsArray.Select(p => p.price).OrderBy(i => i).ToArray();
```

And then add pricesArray to a watch window.

Comment: I don't believe Lamda expressions can be evaluated in the immediate window

Comment: @Dan they can with VS2015.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. They can in vs 2015 as you've said.

Comment: price = new float[DerivSel2.Length];

                for (int k = 0; k < DerivSel2.Length; k++)
                {
                    price[k] = DerivSel2[k].Strike;
                }

                Array.Sort(price);